# What does the %||% operator do in R? Percent Pipe Pipe Percent

Tags: r, plotly

I came across [this](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/utils.R#L60-L62) code when reviewing the R plotly library:

```
modify_list <- function(x, y, ...) {
  modifyList(x %||% list(), y %||% list(), ...)
}
```

What does the "%||%" operator do? And is it specific to plotly?

Comment: Seems to be from `purrr` or `rlang`. From the help page: "This infix function makes it easy to replace `NULL`s with a default value."

Comment: You can see the help page by using quotes, e.g. `?"%||%"` or `help("%||%")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the infix function (from the `rlang` or `purrr` packages) that makes it easy to replace `NULL` with default values. You can find the documentation [here.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.1.6/topics/op-null-default)

You can also search for documentation by typing either of these. To search for anything else, replace the `%||%` and you will be able to look that up as well.

```
> help("%||%")
> ?"%||%"
```

If you want to find it anywhere in any packages you have installed (whether or not they are loaded) you need `help.search("\\%\\|\\|\\%", agrep=FALSE)` (because `%` and `|` are special characters in regular expressions)

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't think to wrap it in quotes when searching for the documentation.

Comment: Very similar to the JavaScript *default operator* (aka logical or): `NaN || 1` returns 1. Everything that is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value default to the other sider.